# Preventing ColorFunction bleed in ListLinePlot

Tags: graphics

Given this dataset (~2100 year precipitation estimates in New Mexico, based on tree-ring data, courtesy of NOAA and Henri Grissino-Mayer)

```
MALPAIS[1] = ToExpression@StringSplit[#, " "] & /@ 
 StringSplit[
  StringTake[
   Import["ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/paleo/treering/\
reconstructions/newmexico/malpais_recon.txt"], 18669 ;; 44215], "\n"]
```

The following:

```
ListLinePlot[#, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, Filling -> Axis, 
       AspectRatio -> 1/5, ImageSize -> 1000, 
       ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[y < 0, Red, Blue]], 
       ColorFunctionScaling -> False] & @(MALPAIS[1] - 
       15.3146`)
```

Results in color-bleed (note, I switched colors from above):

[image]

Presumably due to interpolation, since it it's also there in smaller time windows:

[image]

Is there any option to prevent this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FillingStyle`  is the clue here:

```
GraphicsColumn@{
   ListLinePlot[#[[;; 50]], 
       Frame -> True, Axes -> False,Filling -> Axis, AspectRatio -> 1/5, 
       ImageSize -> 1000, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[y < 0, Red, Blue]],
       ColorFunctionScaling -> False],
    ListLinePlot[#[[;; 50]], 
       Frame -> True, Axes -> False, Filling -> Axis, AspectRatio -> 1/5, 
       ImageSize -> 1000, FillingStyle -> {Red, Blue},   
       ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[y < 0, Red, Blue]], 
       ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
} &@(MALPAIS[1] - 15.3146`)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Whole scale (now with ColorFunction removed and without style):

```
ListLinePlot[#[[;; -1]], Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
    Filling -> Axis, AspectRatio -> 1/5, ImageSize -> 1000, 
    FillingStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotStyle -> None]} &@(MALPAIS[1] - 
   15.3146`
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Arbitrary function to determine separation between blue and red (requested per comment):

```
ListLinePlot[{#[[;; 50]], Table[{x, Sin[x/4]}, {x, #[[;; 50, 1]]}]}, 
   Frame -> True, Axes -> False, Filling -> {2}, AspectRatio -> 1/5, 
   ImageSize -> 1000, FillingStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
   PlotStyle -> None] &@(MALPAIS[1] - 15.3146`)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is it necessary to pass the colors to both FillingStyle and ColorFunction? Seems redundant.

Comment: +1 for the idea. But @alancalvitti is right, ColorFunction needs to be removed.

Comment: @alancalvitti It is. I did it first without (setting `Style->None`) and it's just fine. However, having a line as boundary seems to add a bit of anti-aliasing that I found to be slightly neater. I guess, effects will differ by platform.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Not definitely so, see comment above.

Comment: But what If I hadn't detrended the time series mean, in other words, how to get filling to some nonzero constant k: Function[{x, y}, If[y < k, Red, Blue]] Or even more general function?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, I (temporarily) unaccepted your answer b/c when I try with Just FilingStyle (and nothing else) it looks awful - not as intended. Did you try plotting the entire time series?

Comment: It is much neater with `ColorFunction` and `ColorFunctionScaling` removed on my machine. Those present are causing anti-aliasing problems and still bleed slightly along the curve lines. I can even see the same problems on your small plots. @alancalvitti

Comment: ListLinePlot plots the enveloping line in addition to the filling, whereas with ColorFunction there is no enveloping line, just the filling, which looks much better due to the high frequency oscillations. Requires PlotStyle -> Opacity[0]

Comment: @alancalvitti see update

Comment: @alancalvitti As to your question in the 5th comment: just use `Filling->k` instead of `Filling->Axis`

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, accepted but note this is not a replacement for the more general Function[{x, y}, If[y < ..., Red, Blue]]. I'm reporting to WRI tech support

Comment: @alancalvitti and another update...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, very nice